# OSError: No suitable library found for xls

Tags: python, excel, csv, xls

I've imported pyexcel as pe and am trying to run get_array, and iget_records, on an xls file and I'm getting a strange error, surrounding which I haven't found much documentation. Error: "OSError: No suitable library found for xls."

When I run these commands on Test.csv, I get no issue. But I need it to work for xls files because I'm dealing with non-english characters which I understand don't appear in csv files.

```
my_array = pe.get_array(file_name="Test.xls")
print(my_array)
```

separately,

```
records = pe.iget_records(file_name="/Tests/Test.xls")
 for record in records:
    print(record['alpha'], record['beta'], record['charlie'])
```

Ideas, anyone?

python 3.5.2;
windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this error you need to install `pyexcel-xls`. With pip:

```
pip install pyexcel-xls
```